# Stuck on how to apply dirt/grunge to PS2 style image textures

Tags: texturing

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I'm trying to make my PS2 style textures look dirty/grungy like in Silent Hill 2 but I just can't crack it. I want to use whichever method will give me the most authentic PS2 look.

I'm a total newbie and many people have said "just play around with mix nodes" which is incredibly vague. I understand a decent amount about modeling meshes but texturing is absolutely not my strong suit. Preferably, I would like to make a clean looking building and then paint the dirt and grime onto it wherever I want. I just have no clue how to do that. Is this the wrong method?

I'm not familiar with a lot of the technical terms so if anybody could explain it for a beginner, that would be super helpful. Here are some example images:

https://cdn.openart.ai/stable_diffusion/2f045b3b7fe31da803a4f27b1c3c2a8671b3b32a_2000x2000.webp

https://cdn.openart.ai/stable_diffusion/d830bf91cc68ef71ce2fab8e27b2d1b78043d2c2_2000x2000.webp

https://i.pinimg.com/736x/fb/9a/86/fb9a86d49159aa31b5b768070fdeeebe.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963). Paragraphs are also helpful to make the text readable

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, one of the easiest is to use a dirty texture as factor in a *Mix Shader* between 2 shaders like for example 2 *Principled BSDF*, one is darker (maybe with a high *Roughness*, etc), the other one is brighter (with a low *Roughness*, etc):

[image]

If you want to paint over a repeated texture, create a second UV map with the desired unwrap, plug it into a new *Image Texture* with a transparent texture, use the *Alpha* as factor into a new *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I will definitely use this technique for certain things in my projects! The only problem though is I can't figure out how to control the exact look of the grunge. In the pictures I added, the dirt and stains on the walls are very deliberately placed. I'm starting to wonder if that kind of stuff is done outside of blender. Maybe it's painted directly onto textures before exporting them to 3D. I feel like I'm making this too complicated for myself.

Comment: You can't really control the exact look of the grunge, you can precisely place it on the surface though, you need to unwrap your objects and move the UV faces in the UV Editor

Comment: How are people able to add graffiti or writing onto their textures? I feel like that would have to be hand painted, right? Is there any way to paint on top of a repeating texture without the paint also repeating? On a separate layer or something like in Photoshop?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot